# Convert ssh command line arguments to .ssh/config properties

Tags: ssh

I understand that (almost?) all SSH command line arguments can be replaced with a property in ~/.ssh/config. But it's not at all obvious how to do this systematically: the `man` page for `ssh` only refers loosely to the config page (eg, "Port forwardings can also be specified in the configuration file."). The [`man` page for `ssh_config`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) never refers to command line options.

So, is there a definitive list of the corresponding config parameters and command line options? For example, what does `-R` correspond to?

Comment: AFAIK, you are basically going to need to have the ssh_config and ssh man pages open.  Then switch back and forth.

Comment: That's fine, the hard bit is actually finding which ssh_config option to use for a given command line option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any `ssh` option that can be used in the form `-o Option=Value` can be set in the config file as an `Option    Value` line.  Many of the CLI flags are merely shorthand for long-format options, eg `ssh -2` is equivalent to `ssh -o Protocol=2`, and can thus be set in `.ssh_config` as `Protocol  2`.

I believe that `-R x:rhost:y` corresponds to `RemoteForward x rhost:y`.

But I don't think there's any way to specify a flag that doesn't have a corresponding long-format form.  And on my system the definitive list appears both in the `ssh` and `ssh_config` man pages, in the former under the `-o` flag, and in the latter in the main body of the page, starting very near the top.

Comment: Ok, so .ssh/config options can be converted to command line parameters with -o. But there isn't a way to convert short-form command line parameters, since SSH doesn't conform to GNU command line parameter conventions (eg, -R, --remote-forward).

Comment: Not quite.  There is no way to convert **any** flag options - whether long or short form - to config parameters, **excepting** those that can be expressed on the CLI not only as flags but also as `-o Option=Value`.  **Most** flags do have such an alternative expression; any that don't, can't be so converted.

Comment: Yup, cool. I guess it boils down to this: the man page should be clearer about what the alternative expression is, where there is one.

Answer (score 0):

-G option will display config options.  This script helps to generate a clean entry from ssh command options:

```
ssh2config() {
  host="$(ssh -G "$@" | sed -n 's/^hostname //p')"
  echo "$host"
  comm -23 <(ssh -G "$@" | sort) <(ssh -G abcddd | sort) | sed 's/^/    /'
  echo ''
}
```

Example use:

```
$ ssh2config -p 2222 me@there
there
    hostname there
    port 2222
    user me
```

I have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mikeslattery/a8f9261434ff0b578caff739bd423c50) that will convert your entire ssh shell history.